# Python listからlistの値の抽出

Tags: python

初心者のため、ご教授お願いいたします。

aのlistから、bのlistと一致する値を抽出したいです。

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']
if b in a:
    print ("OK")
else:
    print ("NG")
```

この結果

```
NG
```

と
表示されてしまいます。

Comment: 「変数b」とお書きの一方、コードではbがリストになっています。ほぼ回答になっちゃいますが。

Answer (score 1):

`b`の要素が`a`にも**必ず**含まれているか知りたいということであれば、`a`と`b`を集合に変換して、前者が後者を部分集合として含むか調べます。

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']
if set(b) <= set(a):
    print ("OK")
else:
    print ("NG")
```

もし重複する要素がある場合は、この方法は使えません。代わりに`Counter`などを使って要素を数え上げる方法が考えられます。

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['0','1','2','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']

counter_a = Counter(a)
counter_b = Counter(b)

# `b`の各要素について、その要素が`a`に含まれているか、および`a`に含まれる個数は`b`に含まれる個数より多いか
if all(map(lambda k: k in counter_a and counter_a[k] >= counter_b[k], counter_b)):
    print('OK')
else:
    print('NG')
```

Answer (score 1):

質問からすると、変数 `b` のリストが `a` のリストの中にあれば`OK`が出ます。
`print([i for i in b if i in a])`とすれば一致する値だけが出ます。

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']
if [i for i in b if i in a]:
    print ("OK")
else:
    print ("NG")
```

Answer (score 0):

一致する値を抽出したいとのことですので、集合演算を使うとよいと思います。このプログラムでは変数a, bをそれぞれ集合setへ変換し、
論理積を求める & 演算子を使って共通する要素である0を抽出しています。

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']

set_a = set(a)
set_b = set(b)

# 論理積 共通のもの抽出
set_a & set_b
# >> {'0'}
```

理解を深めるために画像に表してみました。
また、詳しい説明は参考URLを読んでみるとよいと思います。
[image: 論理積 width="50%"]

参考URL:
[Python公式 set](https://docs.python.jp/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)
[Pythonの集合演算 Qiita](https://qiita.com/Tocyuki/items/0bc783daab382ef7a0ec)
[ベン図 Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E5%9B%B3)

Answer (score 0):

ご質問の内容が「`b`に含まれる`a`の要素を出す」ということでしたので、そのリストを返すという意味では下記のような'filter'関数を利用する方法もあります。
（`print('OK')`,`print('NG')`を出すという意味では違うかもしれませんが...）

```
a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
b = ['0']
a_in_b = filter(lambda a_elem: a_elem in b, a)
print(a_in_b) # output: ['0']
```